# If a set is covered by simplices then can it be covered by "almost disjoint" simplices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, computational-topology

Let $x_1,\dots,x_N$ be points in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$ (positive $d$), $r>0$, and consider set $X\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ defined as the collection of all $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ of the form
$$
x = \sum_{j\in I}\, \lambda_i\, x_j,
$$
where $I$ is a non-empty subset of indices in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $\lambda_i\in [0,1]^{\#I}$ sum to one, and $\max_{i,j\in I}\, \|x_i-x_j\|<r$

Does there exist convex sets $C_1,\dots,C_K\subseteq X$ such that

- $\bigcup_{k=1}^K\, C_k = X$ *(not mearly that $C_k$ cover $X$)*,
- For every pair of integers $1\le r<k\le K$
  $$
  \tilde{C_k}\cap \tilde{C}_r = \emptyset,
  $$
  where $\tilde{C}_k$ is obtained from $C_k$ by contracting infinitesimally towards $C_k$'s barycenter $c_k$; i.e.:
  $$
  \tilde{C}_k := \bigcup_{0\le t<1}\, \{s(c-c_k) + c_k:\, c\in C_k\}
  .
  $$

**Motivation:**  *The problem arises from trying to cover a Vietoris-Rips complex's shadow by "almost disjoint" covex simplicies.*

Comment: Are you asking whether every convex polyhedron has a triangulation?

Comment: @domotorp Nono, having a cover by convex sets does not imply being convex (e.g. $\{(t,|t|)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\, t\in \mathbb{R}\}$).

Comment: What would this be, $x_i$ or $X$? I think that $X$ is always convex, at least if $n=N$ in your question.